# Uploading XML file to web directory using PHP & MVC

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm having an issue with my php scripts in ASP.NET MVC.
I've deployed to azure services and have double checked that PHP has been enabled.

The php script (upload.php) is:

```
<?php
if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['file'] ['tmp_name'], "Content/{$_FILES['file'] ['name']}")) {
    echo "Programme file uploaded successfully. You will be redirected to the content rater in a few seconds..";
    header("refresh:3; url=Home/Index");
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "XML file not uploaded successfully. Unexpected error.";
    header("refresh:3; url=Home/Index");
    exit;
}?>
```

I'm attempting to upload the file to the default created folder (in visual studio) 'Content'. I've tried typing the location as (and all have failed):

- ~/Content/
- /Content/
- Content/

My form is as follows:

```
<form action="/Scripts/php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label>Select file:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload">

    </form>
```

No matter what happens, I'm always taken to the failure message.

I thought my script could be wrong so I've tried the script from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) (the image upload example) and that always fails too.

After some research it seems as though you're unable to upload to your own web directory on Azure - Is this true?

**What are my options if this is?**

I also have to use php as it's required by a task I'm trying to complete.

Answer (score 0):

After a little fiddling around with your code, I've gotten something that works!

This should work perfectly for you just change the `$target_dir`. I've tested this on my website. I had the same problems you had with your provided PHP code which leads me to believe that azure is not blocking any type of uploading.

It would be worthwhile doing some checks such as file type, file size and whether the file already exists for security however.

If you are still having problems use `var_dump($_FILES);` as it simply prints out the variable, this will show whether you actually get the file.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "Content/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        // Success

        print "Received {$_FILES['file']['name']} - its size is {$_FILES['file']['size']}";


    } else {
        // Failed
        print "Upload failed!";
        var_dump($_FILES);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi..
Thanks for your efforts however this doesn't seem to work for me. When I hit submit, the screen just goes white and no message is printed.

Comment: I had to remove the initial 'if' statement to get it to show the error. The dump displays correctly but I'm still unsure why the upload is failing.

Comment: @Glitchezz, I suggest you could FTP to your website and check your files uploaded whether is in your content floder. And if you used the Azure website service, I think you'd better to store your files into Azure storage.